# How to send an Image or bytes array from Image in a JSON from Client to backend Server and then store it in Mongodb

Tags: python, json, mongodb, image, rabbitmq

I'm working on a Microservices Project, I'm using Python as a language and RabbitMQ as Message broker. I'm working on an App Store application and I'm facing this problem that the frontend should send me some data in a JSON which include for example (name of the app -> str, title of the app -> str, image or images of the app -> image ....) and that will be sent as a Request over RabbitMQ, the backend should consume that Request and store those data in a Mongodb database and then return a Response for example {"Success": true}.

I've tried so many things, I figured out how to store an Image in the Database. What I didn't figure out is how to send that Image data in a JSON. I tried base64 encoding, utf8, latin1 but None of it works because type bytes is not JSON serializable as the Error said. I searched a lot in the Internet but I didn't find exactly what I'm looking for although sometimes there is a similar questions but I tried almost everything and they didn't provide what I'm looking for.

```
  data = {
"tool_owner": "John",
"developer": "John",
"icon": # icon of the app,
 "images": # list of images,
"rating": {"user": "daniel", "date": str(now), "number": 5},
    }

   d = json.dumps(data) # this is my goal. to send the data as a JSON
   temp = json.loads(d) # and receive it in the backend and parse it so I 
     can retrieve the data and store it in mongodb
```

in the first time, I face this error:

> TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable.

I tried to look how can I convert bytes to strings so that I can send it in a JSON but what I found didn't work for me since I tried base64 encoding and latin1 encoding...

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary must contain bytes objects, which is not supported by the json standard.

You can use `jsonextra` for serialization/deserialization to overcome this issue.

`$ pip install jsonextra`

```py
import jsonextra as json

d = {...}  # contains bytes objects
x = json.dumps(d)
y = json.loads(x)

assert d == y
```

See https://github.com/den4uk/jsonextra for more information.